# Is it possible to make Firebird database backup via SQL?

Tags: delphi, firebird

I need my software to make hot backups of a firebird database.
Using gbak is the official way of doing that. But using an external tool will force me to get through the hassle of ensuring that the tool is in the system PATH or that I have the actual location of gbak.exe. If possible I want to avoid this.

So, are there any options of doing something like

```
BACKUP DATABASE TO location_of_backup;
```

I am using Delphi XE4, Firebird 2.1 and DBExpress, not an option to install third parties here.

Comment: Without any 3rd party library and/or tools, I guess your only option is to run against the [client library](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/ufb-cs-clientlib.html). [This](http://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/design/doc_181) might be a starting point.

Comment: Firebird can create a backup through the services API, if you have an access component that implements the services API, then you can create a backup.

Comment: You can take 3rd-party lib and cut only backup/restore part of it skipping all the rest. For example from Unified Interbase library.
Also, for *hot* backups one may consider using `nbak` rather than `gbak`

Comment: There is one more difference, in client+server model. When you use gbak/nbak to make backup - the real process of backing up is being performed on client computer and output file is created on client. When you use Firebird Services API, then backing up is performed on server and output file is created on server.

Comment: If requirement to only use DB Express and SQL commands is absolute, then you can create server-side plugin, that would make back-ups after receiving your custom SQL command. Though i believe proper way would be using Services API via UIB or IBX supplemental to DBX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible with SQL.

With Delphi XE4 you can use IBExpress (TIBBackup) to make backup easily. You don't need gbak.exe.

FireDac can also make this if you get it (TADIBBackup).

```
ADIBBackup1.DriverLink := ADPhysIBDriverLink1;

ADIBBackup1.UserName := 'sysdba';
ADIBBackup1.Password := 'masterkey';
ADIBBackup1.Host := 'db_srv_host';
ADIBBackup1.Protocol := ipTCPIP;

ADIBBackup1.Database := 'e:\ib\addemo.fdb';
ADIBBackup1.BackupFiles.Add('e:\ib\addemo.backup');

ADIBBackup1.Backup;
```